# How to prevent a FlatList from re-rendering when state changes in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a FlatList in my code that re-renders each time I make a state change (setMatchIndex state).
I need it to not re-render, and I've tried memo, and useCallback, but can't figure out the problem. Please assist

Here's my code:

```
const Home = ()=>{

const [matchIndex, setMatchIndex] = useState(0);

return(
      <FlatList
        data={results}
        horizontal
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        renderItem={({item, index})=>{
          //we set the gradient colot of the component based on the component(index) clicked
          let firstColor = index === matchIndex ? COLORS.secondary : '#232232';
          let secondColor = index === matchIndex ? COLORS.secondary : '#232232';
            
          return (
              <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.6} style={styles.liveGame} onPress={()=> setMatchIndex(index)}>
                <LinearGradient
                  colors={[firstColor, secondColor]}
                  start={{x: 0, y: 1}}
                  end={{x: 1, y: 1}}
                  style={{height: '100%', width: '100%', borderRadius: 20,}}
                >
                  <View style={styles.tournamentContainer}>
                    <View style={styles.tournamentIconWrapper}>
                      <Image source={item.fixture.tournament} resizeMode='contain' style={styles.tournamentIcon}/>
                    </View>
                  </View>
                  <View style={styles.liveTeamsContainer}>
                    <Image source={item.teams.home.logo} resizeMode='contain' style={styles.liveTeam}/>
                    <Image source={item.teams.away.logo} resizeMode='contain' style={styles.liveTeam}/>     
                  </View>
                  <Text style={styles.liveTeamName}>{item.teams.home.name}   {item.teams.home.score}</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.liveTeamName}>{item.teams.away.name}   {item.teams.away.score}</Text>
                </LinearGradient>
      
              </TouchableOpacity>
          )
        }}
        keyExtractor={(item , index) => index }
      />

)

}
```

Comment: Why do you need to avoid a re-render?  There's no way to update a state without triggering a render, that's how React works. At most, you could avoid to re-render list items creating a component for them and wrapping it using `React.memo`. Is this your purpose?

Comment: @MircoBellagamba yes, thats what i want to do

Answer (score 0):

The most simple and used approach to do this is by wrapping the whole function call in a [`useCallback`](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useCallback), with the right dependencies. You have to remember that `renderItem` expects a function and the react way to memoize function calls is to wrap it in `useCalback`. Do not generate the function again and again.

And to prevent rerenders, [memoize](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/memo) the individual list component so that it only re-renders when it has to. Pass `firstColor`, `secondColor` as prop, and the component will only re-render when it changes.

```
const WrapperComp = React.memo(({firstColor , secondColor}) => {

return (<TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.6} style={styles.liveGame} onPress={()=> setMatchIndex(index)}>
                <LinearGradient
                  colors={[firstColor, secondColor]}
                  start={{x: 0, y: 1}}
                  end={{x: 1, y: 1}}
                  style={{height: '100%', width: '100%', borderRadius: 20,}}
                >
                  <View style={styles.tournamentContainer}>
                    <View style={styles.tournamentIconWrapper}>
                      <Image source={item.fixture.tournament} resizeMode='contain' style={styles.tournamentIcon}/>
                    </View>
                  </View>
                  <View style={styles.liveTeamsContainer}>
                    <Image source={item.teams.home.logo} resizeMode='contain' style={styles.liveTeam}/>
                    <Image source={item.teams.away.logo} resizeMode='contain' style={styles.liveTeam}/>     
                  </View>
                  <Text style={styles.liveTeamName}>{item.teams.home.name}   {item.teams.home.score}</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.liveTeamName}>{item.teams.away.name}   {item.teams.away.score}</Text>
                </LinearGradient>
      
              </TouchableOpacity>);

});
```

Use the memoized component in your `useCallback`:

```
const renderItem = useCallback(({item, index})=>{

          let firstColor = index === matchIndex ? COLORS.secondary : '#232232';
          let secondColor = index === matchIndex ? COLORS.secondary : '#232232';
            
          return (<WrapperComponent firstColor={firstColor} secondColor={secondColor} />);
              
        },[]);
```